# UV islands joining when model vertices merged

Tags: uv

I’m working with an imported 3D model someone else made, and it has duplicate vertices and edges: for example, there’s one set of vertices that defines where the torso ends and another set that define where the armpit begins. If I try texture-painting across the boundary, there’s always a big seam visible, even in-game.
[image: Seam visible]

I found that I can get rid of the seam by going into edit mode and merging the duplicate vertices together (Vertex Context Menu -> Merge Vertices -> By Distance), and this joins the torso and armpit together seamlessly:
[image: Seam not visible]

But then when I go to export the model, Blender gets confused: when it deleted vertices in the 3D model, I guess it didn’t understand how to join-together the corresponding UV vertices… so it just drew lines between all of them to connect the “identical” ones. This is problematic for obvious reasons:
[image: UV islands joined together]

The weird thing is that the UV map doesn’t get messed-up the moment I merge vertices in the 3D model (second image), it gets messed-up only when I export the character model and look at it later (third image). Any idea what’s going on here? The UV map doesn’t seem to have any issues while I’m working on the object, so why would it wait until I’m finished to get confused? How do I get Blender to update the UV map / texture image so that the model I export looks exactly like the one I've got while I'm working on it in Object/Edit/Texture Painting view?